# No numpy version specified: remove warning from conda recipe

Tags: conda

This conda recipe (full syntax [here](https://github.com/arqive/qlib/blob/main/qcon/meta.yaml)) ---

```
package:
  name: qcon
  version: 2020.02.05

source:
  - git_url: https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb.git
    git_depth: 1

build:
  script:
    - ARCH=l #[linux]
    - ARCH=m #[osx]
    - ARCH="$ARCH"64 #[x86_64]
    - mkdir -p $PREFIX/bin
    - cp $SRC_DIR/$ARCH/qcon $PREFIX/bin

test:
  commands:
    - echo \\\\ | qcon # [linux64]
```

produces warning:

```
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
```

Is it possible to get rid of the warning? The binary being packaged is standalone and does not depend on Python or numpy at all.

Full log context is available in this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/danielkrizian/12af52e4bfa5d8c1af55d558220a79ef)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are running conda-build and that is where you are getting the warning.

Yes, it is possible to get rid of the warning.

However, it will declare to conda-build to use a numpy version. If that doesn't bother you, because is not needed, run the
conda-build with the option: --numpy NUMPY version installed on the environment will make the info/warning message disappear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).